# How can I format a list to print each element on a separate line in python?

Tags: python, list, format, line

How can I format a list to print each element on a separate line?
For example I have:

```
mylist = ['10', '12', '14']
```

and I wish to format the list so it prints like this:

```
10
12
14
```

so the \n, brackets, commas and '' is removed and each element is printed on a separate line
Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can just use a simple loop: -

```
>>> mylist = ['10', '12', '14']
>>> for elem in mylist:
        print elem 

10
12
14
```

Comment: This would actually work better than `str.join` which expects each element to be a `str`.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thank to notice, see my comment below for a workaround using `str.join` even without all elements being `str`.

Answer (score 134):

Embrace the future! Just to be complete, you can also do this the Python 3k way by using the [print function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print):

```
from __future__ import print_function  # Py 2.6+; In Py 3k not needed

mylist = ['10', 12, '14']    # Note that 12 is an int

print(*mylist,sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
10
12
14
```

Eventually, `print` as Python statement [will go away...](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/) Might as well start to get used to it.

Comment: This answer is cool and its ease included in the usual print statement rather than in loops.

Comment: Brilliant! I never thought of unpacking a list in the context of `print()`. I've long wondered how to implement this in a simple way. Much prefer this to looping or calling `str` functions.

Comment: why is the * necessary here before `mylist`?

Comment: even if I removed `sep` parameter the items were being displayed in new lines. But removing `*` made list printing inline. Why so?

Comment: @Pstr [Check this out](https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558)

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Brilliant! +1

Answer (score 62):

Use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
In [27]: mylist = ['10', '12', '14']

In [28]: print '\n'.join(mylist)
10
12
14
```

Comment: As inspectorG4dget said, this require every element to be `str`. A simple workaround would be `print '\n'.join(map(str, myList))`.

Comment: this should be accepted as correct answer, it is far better than doing a loop

Comment: @SergeyAntopolskiy I wonder if doing a loop is actually that bad. The loop just reads the values and outputs them. Whereas the join results in the creation of a new string in the memory containing all the values and then prints it out. That could result in a performance penalty for long lists IMO.

Comment: @JigarMehta you may have a point there. at least, this should be accepted as *a* correct answer, if not *the* correct answer