# Print each line of a variable into list elements in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print each line into a list element.

Currently I have:

```
Variable = apple
           ball
           chart
           desk
```

I want it into ['apple', 'ball', 'chart', 'desk']. I tried append and I get the error str object has no attribute append...

I think it is the inverse of [How can I format a list to print each element on a separate line in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443588/how-can-i-format-a-list-to-print-each-element-on-a-separate-line-in-python)

THis is the code I have so far:

```
for entry in variable.strip().split(","):

    variable_final = entry.lstrip()
    print variable_final
```

The above code prints out:

```
apple
ball
chart
desk
```

but when I do print [variable_final] it prints out each line as a list.

Note: I still cant figure out a way to do this. Eventually all I need to do is print these lines vertically. I had asked this question earlier but it was made duplicate... I cannot find a way to print multiple lines vertically or print multiple lists vertically...

```
a b c d
p a h e
p l a s
l l r k
e   t
```

Comment: YOu have clearly tried some code - can you post that. BTW - you don't "print" to a list - so you need to be clearer what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh btw, I use the strip and lstrip to remove the white spaces and new line characters in "entry".

Answer (score 1):

If `Variable` is an actual variable name that contains a multi-line string, similar to this:

```
Variable = "\ta\n\tb\n\tc\n\td"
```

then you could do:

```
str(Variable.replace("\n", "").split("\t")[1:])
```

and you can adjust this as necessary for the specific locations of the newline, tab, or other special characters in your variable string.

If the `Variable =` portion is actually part of the printed string itself, and the variable is called something else, say `foo`, then you could first do:

```
foo1 = foo[10:] # or however you want to skip past the 'Variable = ' part
```

and then just take care re: whether there is a leading whitespace or tabs when you use `split`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an answer :

if you have this :

```
variable =
"""This is a
multiline string
and I want each line
as a separate entry"""
```

this this code will translate that into a list, with one list entry for each line :

```
lst = variable.split("\n")
```

Comment: Hi I tried this one and it gives me as seperate lists.. i.e., each line as a list and I need each line as an element of a single list...