# pyspark print one item in each line

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In Pyspark, when I try to print a list, I get all the elements printed in the same line :

```
>>> wordslist = words.collect();
>>> wordslist
[(u'crazy', 1), (u'fox', 1), (u'jumped', 1)]
```

Is there any way I could get the output printed one item per line, like this :

```
>>> wordslist
[
(u'crazy', 1),
(u'fox', 1),
(u'jumped', 1)
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same can be achieved using `foreach` in Scala

```scala
mylist.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic python. When you collect a result from an RDD. You obtain a list which you can iterate on and print each element in the format you wish.

I think that the question on how to print a list had been answered so many times in SO.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13443608) is one example.

```
$> mylist = myrdd.collect()
$> for elem in mylist:
$>     print elem
```

You'd also want to check pyspark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.html) .