# How to place a string of words into one column using python

Tags: python

I wish to create a column from the output of this Python script.

```
str ='JJHKEKWPWPWJJENNICNRTKMNWAPOHBYEBSWKL'

n = 10
chunks = [str[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(str), n)]
print(chunks)
```

Output =
['JJHKEKWPWP', 'WJJENNICNR', 'TKMNWAPOHB', 'YEBSWKL']

So that the final output will be.

```
JJHKEKWPWP
WJJENNICNR
TKMNWAPOHB
YEBSWKL
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I format a list to print each element on a separate line in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443588/how-can-i-format-a-list-to-print-each-element-on-a-separate-line-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sep` parameter from `print` and the splat operator:

```py
print(*chunks, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much ...That was the solution I was looking for

Comment: @james Glad to help! If my answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the big checkmark to select it as the accepted answer, so people answering can focus on older questions which still don't have answers.